# Как сделать обработку свойства товаров

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день, такой вопрос нашел данные товаров таобао, выводится в json:

```
{
    "skuProps": [{
        "propId": "20509",
        "propName": "Размер",
        "propNameChina": "尺码",
        "values": [{
            "valueId": "28316",
            "name": "m",
            "nameChina": "m"
        }]
    }, {
        "propId": "1627207",
        "propName": "цвет",
        "propNameChina": "颜色分类",
        "values": [{
            "valueId": "28337",
            "name": "красный",
            "nameChina": "粉红色",
            "imgUrl": "http://gd3.alicdn.com/bao/uploaded/i3/737699529/TB261nLepXXXXcLXXXXXXXXXXXX_!!737699529.jpg"
        }]
    }]
}
```

но понятие не имею как делать обработку свойства товаров например одежда цвет: красный, 87 штук, размер: m, 7 штук, и исходя из выбранное характеристики:

```
{
    "ppathIdmap": {
        "20509:28316;1627207:28337": "3308677261252",
    }
}
```

Json с данными цены и кол-во:

```
{
    "skuModel": {
        "skus": {
            "3308677261252": {
                "priceUnits": [{
                    "display": 3,
                    "price": "99.00"
                }],
                "quantity": 98,
                "quantityText": "98"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

выводит цены и кол-во остаток в нужный блок:

```
<div id="price">цена</div>
<div id="quantity">кол-во</div>
```

Может кто нибудь поможет. В сети не чего не нашел. Html:

```
<ul data-property="Размер">
  <li data-value="20509:28337">
    <a>
      <span>m</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul data-property="Цвет" class="tm-clear J_TSaleProp">
  <li data-value="1627207:28337">
    <a>
      <span>красный</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте @newProgrammer ! Нужно чтобы вы выложили свой код(полностью рабочее HTML, CSS и заготовку JS), в том виде как сейчас выглядит ваш вопрос, шансы на получение ответа минимальные. Я вам минус за вопрос поставлю, а как улучшите его, с радостью минус уберу. Еще я дам вам ссылку на неплохой учебник по JavaScript [**ссылка**](https://learn.javascript.ru/)

Comment: Спасибо за объяснения причини минуса. Постараюсь улучшит вопрос